# Member function for typedef

Tags: c++, wrapper, typedef, member-functions

#### I am wondering if the following is possible in C++.

I have a typedef

```cpp
template<typename T> struct wrapper {};
using vecint = wrapper<std::vector<int>>;
```

and I want to write a function `size` for which I can use member function syntax. I.e. write

```cpp
vecint v{1,3};
v.size();
```

instead of

```cpp
vecint v{1,3};
size(v);
```

#### Why I want to do this

I do not have access to the struct `wrapper`.

When there is another way to accomplish this, I am glad to hear about it. But, also then I am still interested whether this is possible in C++ or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way would be to wrap `struct wrapper` in a new class where you would add the relevant methods:

```
template<typename T>
class my_wrapper: public wrapper {
public:
    using wrapper;        // import parent ctors
    int size {
        return ::size(*this);
    }
};
using vecint = my_wrapper<std::vector<int>>;
```

Then (assuming that the function size is defined *somewhere*), you could do:

```
vecint v{1,3};
v.size();
```